# Cypress how to assert that console was calledWith array of x length?

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, chai

I'm trying to find how to assert that the console log was called with an array of a defined fixed length and I'm not sure how to do that. I'm not very familiar with Mocha/Sinon, which Cypress seems to be using.

To give a bit more of a background of my App does, it's a Queued Editing, I change a few cell and they change color, once I'm ready to click save then it shows an array of all the cells that got changed (in my particular test, 11 got changed). I know how to test the entire `calledWith` comparison but I just want to test the array length and nothing more (since I have random data, I can't test an equal match of data but the array length will be sufficient).

So far I have this code that works for the most part except for the array length

```js
describe('My Sample', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // create a console.log spy for later use
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.spy(win.console, 'log');
    });
  });

it('should click on the "Save" button and expect 2 console log calls with the queue items', () => {
    cy.get('[data-test=save-all-btn]').click();

    cy.get('.unsaved-editable-field')
      .should('have.length', 0);

    cy.window().then((win) => {
      expect(win.console.log).to.have.callCount(2);
      expect(win.console.log).to.be.calledWith(Array[11]); // how to test array length of 11?
    });
  });
```

Also, maybe as a second question, how could we assert that this array contains a certain object property with x value? In Jest we can do it this way. I just haven't seen anything similar in Cypress, is that kind of test possible in Cypress?

```js
// for an array
const oddArray = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13];
test('should start correctly', () => {
  expect(oddArray).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]));
});

// for an array of objects
const users = [{id: 1, name: 'Hugo'}, {id: 2, name: 'Francesco'}];

test('we should have ids 1 and 2', () => {
  expect(users).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining([
      expect.objectContaining({id: 1}),
      expect.objectContaining({id: 2})
    ])
  );
});
```

Comment: For the second question, see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai - `should('contain', ...)` or `include`.

Comment: I'm aware of the `should('contain'` but I don't think it applies with the console log since I think it has to be a Chai assert, but actually I found it under the same page you provided, it's `expect([1,2,3]).to.include(2)`, not sure how that would work with an object property check though